# Wordpress Site Slow Loading Time in Receiving/Waiting

Tags: php, html, wordpress, caching

Trying to get the loading time of a Wordpress website (with three.js) - `https://igotchamedia.com/arvr` down from 6seconds to under 1.5s - the "Waiting" and "Receiving" part of the page loading is taking the bulk of the time. Caching plugins did not help.

[image: Screenshot of Speed Test]

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Open wp-config.php and find line define('DB_HOST', 'localhost:3306'); and change it to define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1:3306');

That will disable DNS lookup so it should be bit faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your times are slow for the initial `Get` parameter for the root document of the site, and that's called Time to First Byte. You have a redirect from the non-https site to the https site, and that is part of the slowness issue.

You can get rid of the redirects depending on how you implement SSL on your site and in WordPress: either by a redirect in `.htacccess` (not the best), or simply being sure your WordPress site and address settings are https and all URLs in the database are https, and then no redirects are needed.

[image]

But overall slow TTFB times are a server lag issue. If you are on a shared host, slow TTFB speeds can be slow because of all the other users of the server. Your overall speed - 4 seconds - is not bad for a very image heavy site with a fairly high number of `http` requests: https://gtmetrix.com/reports/igotchamedia.com/GLQwMRRs

[image]

You can talk to the webhost about the TTBF issues. But GoDaddy shared hosting  is well-known to be a slow.

If you want to get under a few seconds, don't depend on a caching plugin to do all the work. 1) Get a better server and use a CDN; 2) lower the weight of the images and get the total weight of the site under 1 meg; 3) and use a theme that requires fewer scripts and style sheets which result in a high number of `http` requests; and 4) keep your external requests, like third-party fonts, to a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

The vast majority of the time a Wordpress or any website is slow; is because of too much rich media *(video and images)* hosted or used on the site.

Try going back in and optimizing your website's media files for web. Save them at a smaller weight, and use better practices with file extensions. Also, CSS3 techniques are powerful these days and in many cases you don't even need to call so many image files. *ie.* for backgrounds, gradients, shadows, menus, buttons, etc. If you have lots' and lot's of media being hosted on your site, consider the use of a CDN (content delivery network).

Another good practice. Go in and make sure your website was coded properly. Calling external .js files in the footer, html is semantic, etc etc. Test your Wordpress plugins being used. Make sure your Wordpress is up to date, and has correct memory set. Check your developer console for any JavaScript errors or conflicts bogging the site down. Check your Wordpress database for any corruptions.

Lastly, check your host or server environment. Make sure your using the correct version of PHP, you have enough space, everything is efficient etc.

Also, check out these additional site performance optimization tools.

- https://www.pingdom.com/
- https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/

Hope this helps, g'luck!

Comment: Look at the waterfall; it is primarily a TTFB issue, not an image loading issue.